# Spring Integration (SFTP) message source isn't getting more than 1 file per poll despite setting to unlimited

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have following code to read xml files from a sftp server as InputStream:

```
@Configuration
public class SftpConfig {
    ...

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "stream", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay="60000"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> messageSource() {
        SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(template());
        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(sftpProperties.getBaseDir());
        messageSource.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        // messageSource.setMaxFetchSize(-1); no matter what i set this to, it only fetches one file
        return messageSource;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "stream", adviceChain = "after")
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler handle() {
        return message -> {
            Assert.isTrue(message.getPayload() instanceof InputStream, "Payload must be of type $InputStream");
            String filename = (String) message.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE);
            InputStream is = (InputStream) message.getPayload();
            log.info("I am here"); // each poll only prints this once
        };
    }
    ...
}
```

When I debugged or checked the logs for `MessageHanlder$handleMessage`, I continuously only saw one message (file object) came through. And there are more than one `.xml` file sitting on the sftp server as I could verify by seeing file coming through in the next poll. The documentation says

```
    /**
     * Set the maximum number of objects the source should fetch if it is necessary to
     * fetch objects. Setting the
     * maxFetchSize to 0 disables remote fetching, a negative value indicates no limit.
     * @param maxFetchSize the max fetch size; a negative value means unlimited.
     */
    void setMaxFetchSize(int maxFetchSize);
```

So that I fiddled with different numbers but to no avail. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for misleading, but `fetch` doesn't mean `poll`. The fetch options just take as many remote entities to the local cache on a first poll and every single subsequent polls just take entries from that cache until it is exhausted.

The option about max messages per poll belongs to that `@Poller` configuration. See a respective option:

```
/**
 * @return The maximum number of messages to receive for each poll.
 * Can be specified as 'property placeholder', e.g. {@code ${poller.maxMessagesPerPoll}}.
 * Defaults to -1 (infinity) for polling consumers and 1 for polling inbound channel adapters.
 */
String maxMessagesPerPoll() default "";
```

Pay attention to that `1 for polling inbound channel adapters`. That's how you see only one message coming through.

Nevertheless the logic is like push only one message to the channel. There is no batching for how many files you have a the moment. Independently of `fetch` `perPoll` only one message is sent to the channel. Although I agree that with infinite `perPoll` all the messages are sent in the same thread and during the same poll cycle.

Comment: ah, makes sense. Thanks.